# how can insert accents and "ñ" with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing an insert in mysql but all my accents and "ñ"  changes to "?". 
I serched  in internet and I've done this:

I changed the collation of my data base and tables to utf8_spanish_c
I changed my php.ini in default_charset

but I have the problem yet.

what can i do?

Comment: And how did you connect to the database from PHP?

Comment: You are inserting at the DB and the `ñ` is being lost or in PHP?

Comment: Maybe it's not MySQL, maybe the `ñ` is been lost between the form submission and the php script that processes it (has happened to me in JSP).

Comment: convert the $_POST values with utf8decode before insert in mysql = http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php